# OOP Advice to get rid of a switch statement using prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Polymorphism for Transaction in Javascript OOP:

I am attemping to get better at OOP in javascript and am currently working on a OOP solution for handling different types of commercial transactions, Buy, Bid, Etc.

The way that I had it before was I had all the seller actions in one side of an if statement with a switch to process each transaction type.

Then I did the same thing for the buyer.

Going through this I have improved the structure of the code so it's easier to read but I find myself thinking that the "SWITCH" inside processSellerTransactions and processBuyerTransactions are wrong.

if I have all the prototypes setup (buy, bid) etc. I'd like to just call the prototype function directly without having to use the switch statement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction (tutorials etc) or point out what I am doing wrong.

I am getting it (kindof) but it's all still pretty new so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
var Transaction = function(transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
};

Transaction.prototype.buy = function(){
    console.log("Buy");
};

Transaction.prototype.bid = function(){
    console.log("Bid");
};

function Type(transactionType, transactionId) {
    Transaction.call(this, transactionType); 
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
}

Type.prototype = Object.create(Transaction.prototype);

Type.prototype.constructor = Type;

Type.prototype.processSellerTransactions = function(){ 

    switch(this.transactionType) {
        case 'buy':
                  console.log('do the buy logic for seller');
                break;
            case 'bid':
                  console.log('do the bid logic for seller')
                break;
    }
};

Type.prototype.processBuyerTransactions = function(){ 
    switch(this.transactionType) {
        case 'buy':
                 console.log('do the buy logic for buyer');
                break;
            case 'bid':
                 console.log('do the bid logic for buyer')
                break;
  }
};

var user = 'seller';
var transaction_type = 'buy';
var transaction_id = '12345';

var transaction = new Type(transaction_type, transactionId);

if(user == seller)
    transaction.processSellerTransactions();    

if(user == buyer)
    transaction.processBuyerTransactions();
```

---

Thanks to John for the advice about the Strategy Pattern. Here is a simple example in Javascript

[Strategy Pattern In Javascript Example](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/5736427/)

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to do a `BuyType` and a `BidType` subclass of `Transaction`?

Comment: Yes i think that might be it. I want to do whatever I need to do to be able to be extendable fairly quickly. The boss is kind of a crazy maker so say they come in tommorow and say. "We want to allow people to put stuff on hold as well". If it was only the two it would be pretty easy. I am trying to think of future added Transaction Types. Buy, Bid, OnHold, Returned, BackOrdered, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `TransactionType` and abstraction that knows how to process a transaction, then you can use [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to pass the processing on to the `TransactionType`

You can convert this to prototype style

```
function BidTransactionType(){
  this.processSellerTransaction = function(type){
    console.log('process seller transaction')
  }
  this.processBuyerTransaction = function(type){
    console.log('process buyer transaction')
  }
}
function Type(transactionType,
Type.prototype.processSellerTransactions = function(){ 

    switch(this.transactionType) {
        case 'buy':
                  console.log('do the buy logic for seller');
                break;
            case 'bid':
                  console.log('do the bid logic for seller')
                break;
    }
};
function Type(transactionType, transactionId) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType; 
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
}

Type.prototype.processBuyerTransactions = function(){ 
    transactionType.processBuyerTransaction(this);
};

Type.prototype.processSellerTransactions = function(){ 
    transactionType.processSellerTransaction(this);
};

var user = 'seller';
var transaction_type = new BuyerType();
var transaction_id = '12345';

var transaction = new Type(transaction_type, transactionId);
```

The upside to this is you can create more transactions types without having to change your `Type` object, keeping with [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

Comment: Yes a strategy pattern is exactly what I would like.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of that switch statement by having a BuyerTransaction and a SellerTransactionClass. You then move that logic inside another function which instantiates the right type.

e.g

```
function createTransaction(person){
if(person === 'buyer'){
  return new BuyerTransaction();
}
return new SellerTransaction();
}

var BuyerTransaction = function(){}
BuyerTransaction.prototype = Object.create(Transaction.prototype);
BuyerTransaction.prototype.buy = function(){}
BuyerTransaction.prototype.bid = function(){}

var SellerTransaction = function(){}
SellerTransaction.prototype = Object.create(Transaction.prototype);
SellerTransaction.prototype.buy = function(){}

//at runtime
var transaction = createTransaction('buyer');
transaction.buy();
```

Comment: like this as well.